# How to display a name value instead of the ID of that value without refreshing the page (using jQuery)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo

For reference, I am using a mySQL database. This must be done without page refresh (so it needs to be done using AJAX [I'm using jQuery for my AJAX functions]). For example purposes say there is a person who has a first name, last name, and they get assigned to a minimum of one job or a maximum of 2 jobs. There are 2 tables:

The first table takes the id from the job table and uses it as a foreign key.

Table "tbl_person":

```
+------+-------------+------------+--------+--------+
| p_ID | p_firstName | p_lastName | p_job1 | p_job2 |
+------+-------------+------------+--------+--------+
|   1  | Mike        | Jefferson  |      3 |      1 |
|   2  | Jack        | Frost      |      2 |        |
+------+-------------+------------+--------+--------+
```

Table "tbl_job"

```
+--------+------------+
| job_ID |  job_Name  |
+--------+------------+
|      1 | Clerk      |
|      2 | Programmer |
|      3 | Mechanic   |
+--------+------------+
```

I want to display the tbl_person table with the job_Name from the tbl_job table. As of now the php code by itself properly displays this with a page refresh. However, with my current jQuery code, only the data from tbl_person is displayed.

Example of what jQuery currently displays (displays all entries using one for example):

```
+------+-----------+---+---+----+------+
| Mike | Jefferson | 3 | 1 |Edit|Delete|
+------+-----------+---+---+----+------+
```

Example of what the php code does/what I want the jQuery code to do (displays all entries using one for example):

```
+------+-----------+----------+-------+----+------+
| Mike | Jefferson | Mechanic | Clerk |Edit|Delete|
+------+-----------+----------+-------+----+------+
```

The main part of the code is below. I want to display what I am logging to the console in the html table so that it is displayed on the web page (see above tables):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "person.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log($("#job1 option:selected").text());
        console.log($("#job2 option:selected").text());
    },
    error: function () {
        //insert error alert
    }
});
```

functions pdo file not included (contains db functions)

PHP file with input data and display formatting (html structure):
person.php

```
//below code posts new info to database
<?php
$pdo = new functions();
$getPerson = $pdo->getPerson("");
$PersonList = $pdo->getPersonList();

if(isset($_POST["p_ID"])){
    if($_POST["p_ID"] != ''){
        $pdo->updatePerson($_POST);
    }else{
        $pdo->addPerson($_POST);
    }
exit();
}

if(isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $pdo->deletePerson($_GET["id"]);
}
?>

//html form for entering info (this should pop up with jQuery code when clicking new entry button

<div id="personform" title="Person Form">
<form name="personedit" id="personedit" method="post" action="person.php">
<!--//hidden section for the id to pass for the record update-->
<input name="p_ID" type="hidden" value="" />
<fieldset>
<legend>People</legend>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><label for="p_firstName">First Name:</label><br /></th>
        <td><input type="text" class="name" name="p_firstName" value="" size="18" maxlength="25"/></td>
        <th><label for="p_lastName">Last Name:</label><br /></th>
        <td><input type="text" class="name" name="p_lastName" value="" size="18" maxlength="25"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>First Job:</th>
        <td>
            <select name="p_job1" id="job1" class="name">
                <option value=""></option>
                <?php 
                    $getJobs = $pdo->getJobs();
                    foreach($getJobs as $row){  
                        if($row["job_ID"] == $getPerson["p_job1"]){
                            $selected = "selected = selected";
                        }else{
                            $selected = "";
                        }
                        echo "<option value='" . $row['job_ID'] . "' $selected>" . $row['job_name'] . "</option>";
                    }
                ?>                  
            </select>   
        </td>
        <th>Second Job:</th>
        <td>
            <select name="p_job2" id="job2" class="name">
                <option value=""></option>
                <?php 
                    foreach($getJobs as $row){  
                        if($row["job_ID"] == $getPerson["p_job2"]){
                            $selected = "selected = selected";
                        }else{
                            $selected = "";
                        }
                        echo "<option value='" . $row['job_ID'] . "' $selected>" . $row['job_name'] . "</option>";
                    }
                ?>                  
            </select>               
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>           
</fieldset>        
</form>
</div>

/*html code to display the person table data in table format with the job name 
displayed (not the id) */

<a class="add" href="person.php">New Entry</a>

<h1>Person List</h1>
<div class="float-left">
    <table id="tbllist">
        <tr>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>First Job</th>
            <th>Second Job</th>
            <th colspan="2">Action</th>
        </tr>
    <?php   
        foreach ($PersonList as $row) {
            echo "<tr class='fadeaway" . $row['p_ID'] . "'>";       
            echo "<td><input type='hidden' id='p_lastName".$row['p_ID']."' value='".$row['p_lastName']."'>".$row['p_lastName']."</td>";
            echo "<td><input type='hidden' id='p_firstName".$row['p_ID']."' value='".$row['p_firstName']."'>".$row['p_firstName']."</td>";
            echo "<td><input type='hidden' id='job_Name1".$row['p_ID']."' value='".$row['p_job1']."'>".$row['job_Name1']."</td>";
            echo "<td><input type='hidden' id='job_Name2".$row['p_ID']."' value='".$row['p_job2']."'>".$row['job_Name2']."</td>";
            echo "<td><a href='#' class='edit' id='".$row['p_ID']."'>Edit</a></td>";
            echo "<td><a href='#' class='delete' id='".$row['p_ID']."'>Delete</a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

Portion of Javascript code

```
//this section is in a separate js file 
// JavaScript Document
function() {
    var data = $($(this).data('formID')).closest("form").serialize();   

    if($($(this).data('formID')).valid()){  
        var ID = $(this).data('ID'); //gets ID of table row for editing

        //This function finds the class name of each input for use in the add section
        var inputname = $(".name").map(function() {
            r = $(this).attr("name");
            return r;
        }).get();

        //This function finds the value of each input for use in the add section
        var inputval = $(".name").map(function() {
            p = $(this).val();
            return p;
        }).get();

        //code to change array positioning so that the table is printed correctly.


        /*AJAX code for name value (this is what needs to be changed) */
        $.ajax({
            url: "person.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {

            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Sorry, there was a problem!');   
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            'url': '',
            'type': 'POST',
            'dataType': 'text', 
            'data': data,
            'success': function(data){

                if (action == "edit") {

                    var tblval = "";
                    //loops through the number of input names and adds a table value for each one
                    for (i = 0; i < inputname.length; i++) {
                        console.log(inputval[i]);
                        var val = inputval[i];
                        var tblval = tblval + "<td><input type='hidden' id="+inputname[i]+ID+" value='"+val+"'>"+val+"</td>";
                    }
                    edit = $("#tbllist .fadeaway"+ID+"").html(tblval+"<td><a href='#' class='edit' id='"+ID+"'>Edit</a></td>"+"<td><a href='#' class='delete' id='"+ID+"'>Delete</a></td>");
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am fairly new to AJAX and jQuery so some of this code is probably not best practice.

Comment: That's a huge wall of text, can you condense it down a bit?

Comment: You don't need page refresh NOR any additional requests if you already know what you need. You need to `JOIN` the job table though in your initial query

Comment: One can only assume, but if your AJAX-loaded script calls `$pdo->getPerson($p_ID)`, you should add the `JOIN` to its query the same way you did for `$pdo->getPersonList()`.

Comment: I did not bother reading all of your code but aren't you supposed to do an AJAX GET or POST call to an url (php file/path) where your getPerson function gets called. You could do it by a) butting getPerson into separate file or b) by checking how the php file is accessed and call getPerson when requirements are met.

Comment: If I were using buttons, I'd surely voted to close this question with reason "It is unclear what is asked here"

Comment: The code is attached to the submit button in a jQuery modal dialog box. It is still a form submission. The dialog box pops up instead of the form being on the page. I just reversed my edits to include the rest of the code again. 

Using PHP the code works perfectly fine. I need to convert the PHP to jQuery. The tables at the top explain the problem and what I want to do.

Comment: What does foreighn key to do with javascript? Reading title, one would tell it's database related question, but in the body it's all about JS/AJAX. Can't you make our mind what are you asking for?

Comment: I was not sure how else to describe as anything other than a foreign key value. The ID number gets posted in a table using the javascript code instead of the value. In the PHP code, the value gets posted, which is what I want jQuery to do. Say if I hit the edit button (this is in html) the form pops up with the data and the select boxes. If I press submit without changing anything, then the values from the select boxes are replaced with numbers (their ID values). If I refresh the page, the values are displayed again. I want the values to be displayed regardless of the page refresh.

Comment: I was thinking that the getPersonList function is the reason why the values are displayed properly while refreshing the page, but I'm not sure how to load that into the javascript code either if that is what needs to be done. It's taken me time to try and figure out how to ask this as well so if it is unclear I understand and I will try to explain it better if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other issues with the code I have written, but I have solved this particular issue by changing this section:

```
var inputval = $(".name").map(function() {
    p = $(this).val();
    return p;
}).get();
```

to this:

```
var inputval = $(".name").map(function() {
    if (!$(this).is("select")) {    
        p = $(this).val();
    } else {
        p = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    }
    return p;
}).get();
```